# Where to get the promotion-info-id in Facebook API

Tags: facebook

I looked over the API doc but it doesn't say where to get the promotion info id.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/promotion-info

Comment: Have you tried just using the id of a promoted post?

Comment: Yup I tried that but that will just return info about the posts since the route is /2.3/{post-id}/

Comment: Ah, yeah, makes sense … I suppose this should be somewhere in the depths of the Marketing API documentation.

Comment: Reported bug https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1513655582287048/

Answer (score 2):

Answer given by official sources from Facebook for the [bug I reported](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1513655582287048/).

Both [Expirable](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/expirable-post/) and [Scheduled](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/expirable-post/) posts contain a Promoted Info object.

I would recommend looking into the Insights API  to get better metrics on your promotions. Please see the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights-api) on this for more information.